# Method reaches halfway then an error occurs?

Tags: java, android, error-handling, gps, location

I've got my method, it reaches about half way to setTestProviderEnabled, but then for some reason throws an **IllegalArgumentException** saying "Provider gps Unknown"?

Any ideas of how to remove the error? I simply want it to set my phones location to the coordinates. I am testing using a device. Do I need to disable my GPS?

**Method:**

```
private void setMockLocation() {
    {
        Context context = this;
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy( Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE );
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider( criteria, true );

        if ( provider == null ) {
            Log.e( TAG, "No location provider found!" );
            return;
        }

        locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        Location newLocation = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        newLocation.setLatitude(55.9500);
        newLocation.setLongitude(3.1833);

        newLocation.setAccuracy(500);

        mLocationManager.setTestProviderEnabled
                (
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        true
                );

        mLocationManager.setTestProviderStatus
                (
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        LocationProvider.AVAILABLE,
                        null,
                        System.currentTimeMillis()
                );

        mLocationManager.setTestProviderLocation
                (
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        newLocation
                );
    }
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
05-10 21:25:17.061  23061-23061/com.example.ankhit.saveme E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provider "gps" unknown
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1429)
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
            at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.setTestProviderEnabled(ILocationManager.java:1009)
            at android.location.LocationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(LocationManager.java:1269)
            at com.example.ankhit.saveme.UserLocation.setMockLocation(UserLocation.java:241)
            at com.example.ankhit.saveme.UserLocation.access$000(UserLocation.java:42)
            at com.example.ankhit.saveme.UserLocation$4.onClick(UserLocation.java:175)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4439)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18398)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: on what device are you testing ?

Comment: My phone its running API 21 the OS is 4.2

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if the `LocationManagers GPS_PROVIDER` is enabled

```
if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
}
```

Comment: Where will I add that in regards to my code? Also, i do not have any variable called locationListener? Please elaborate a bit more I am new to all of this.